# How do I remove the action bar from the app?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to remove the action bar from the app that I'm developing in NativeScript, I remove all the code that was related to the action bar (html and css code) but it continues appearing on the app.

**HTML:**

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout class="page p-t-15">

            <Image src="~/app/img/logo.png" ></Image>
            <Label class="m-t-10 text-center" text="Login" label.Alignment = "top";></Label>

        <TextField class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalization="none"
            [(ngModel)]="email"></TextField>

        <TextField class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" hint="Password" secure="true" autocorrect="false" autocapitalization="none"
            [(ngModel)]="password"></TextField>

        <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="SIGN IN" (tap)="onSigninButtonTap()"></Button>

        <Label class="m-t-10 text-center" text="______ or ______"></Label>

        <Button class="btn btn-outline" (tap)="onLoginWithSocialProviderButtonTap()" text="Log in with Social Provider"></Button>

        <Label class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" text="Forgot password?" (tap)="onForgotPasswordTap()"></Label>

        <Label class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" text="Não tem conta?" (tap)="onNaoTemContaTap()"></Label>
        <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="Sign UP" [nsRouterLink]="['/browse']" pageTransition="slide" clearHistory="true"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**CSS:**

```
    StackLayout {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#000000,#439B9B , #000000); 
}
```

Comment: Not sure which part of that is the action bar, but you could add some CSS to completely hide it, such as `display: none;`

Comment: @Protozoid you cant do that in nativescript, not for the action bar atleast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page(s) that you want to remove the action bar, add `import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";`, then add `private page: Page` inside your constructor. This then allows you to do `this.page.actionBarHidden = true;`.

Somewhat like the following:

```
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
...
export class ... {
    constructor(private page: Page) {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note: this code only works in nativescript with angular, the idea applies to vanilla nativescript but the code is different

Comment: With this approach you would have to do this on each page, which can become tedious. It's way better to use the `actionBarVisibility` property on the `page-router-outlet` component.

Comment: actually, there is a couple of ways to disable it on every page. you can change the app's activity types to remove the action bar (you change the app type the projects builds against) and you can hide the action bar from every page by using the code above in a certain place but i unfortunately cant remember where

Comment: Another flaw of this approach is that you are hiding the action bar dynamically post-factum. This means that the action bar is initially shown and when the Angular component is instantiated, it hides it. This leads to numerous visual glitches particularly on older devices. The `actionBarVisibility` property tells the navigation controller to never show the action bar. This is better from both performance and ux point of view.

Answer (score 2):

With NativeScript 5.0 you have a new property [`actionBarVisibility`](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/frame#action-bar-visibility) on the `Frame` component. You can set it to `never` and you will never see an `ActionBar` in the pages navigated in this `Frame`. It eliminates the need to hide the `ActionBar` manually on each page.

The same property is exposed for the `page-router-outlet` component in Angular.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon If you are having a problem with the property, please log it in github. It's in the nativescript-angular package since 6.2.0. Here is the changelog - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-2

Comment: i'm not having trouble with the property? i'm just pointing out that your answer isnt for angular whereas mine is

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. For Angular, you set the property on `page-router-outlet`. Are you having a problem with the wording?

Comment: for angular, the solution is what i have posted in my answer. unless it got changed, angular doesn't use "frames"

Comment: It does use "frames" under the hood. In fact the `page-router-outlet` is a "frame" which is the reason why it has this property.

Comment: The OP asked how to remove the action bar from his app. The approach in your answer removes the action bar from a single page. We added the `actionBarVisibility` property exactly for the scenario the OP needs - to remove the action bar globally. It's the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `actionBarVisibility` on the page-router-outlet works like a charm. Thanks, Martin!

Answer (score 0):

For Vue just use Page with `actionBarHidden`:

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
      ...
  </Page>
</template>
```